# Angular 15 - Activated Route snapshot params returns null

Tags: router, angular15

I'm new in Angular and I'm facing a problem retrieving data through navigation. I tried a lot of things, but none it's not working for the case I want.

Here's my code:

App-Module-Routing

```
path: '',
                    component: AppLayoutComponent,
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: '',
                            loadChildren: () =>
                                import(
                                    './demo/components/home-page/home-page.module'
                                ).then((m) => m.HomePageModule),
                        },
                        {
                            path: 'dashboard/:vin',
                            loadChildren: () =>
                                import(
                                    './demo/components/dashboard/dashboard.module'
                                ).then((m) => m.DashboardModule),
                        },
                    ],
```

Father component

```
openDashboard(vin: string) {
        this.route.navigate(['/dashboard', vin])
    }
```

Child Component

```
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['vin']
    }
```

I also tried with subscribe, but it did not worked

The only way that I made it worked was to change to

```
openDashboard(vin: string) {
        this.route.navigate(['/dashboard', {vin: vin} ])
    }
```

But my URL came out as http://localhost:4200/dashboard;vin=8AJAA3DD1M1236302 while I want http://localhost:4200/dashboard/8AJAA3DD1M1236302 as I set for the path.